# Time format issue with go language

Tags: go, time, datetime-conversion

I am using go 14.4 version and seeing a particular issue when converting time. So I need current time to be converted to this format `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z` and using below code

```golang
currentTime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
currentDateTime, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", currentTime)
```

But getting output as "0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"
when running same in go playground getting output as "2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC"

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You're ignoring the error returned by `time.Parse`. Don't ignore errors.

Comment: Just to note re. "I am using go 14.4" - I assume you mean 1.14.4, which puts you about two years out of date. You should definitely consider upgrading for current security and performance fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly don't ignore errors - that is why you are getting a "zero" time - because the time string was not parsed correctly.

Since you are using `RFC3339` to format the time string:

```
currentTime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
```

simply use the same format `time.RFC3339` to parse it back:

```
//currentDateTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", currentTime) // wrong format
currentDateTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, currentTime)

if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

---

FYI heres a list of the `time` package's [format strings](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants).